# blowing-up preserves the first Betti number?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, blowup, k3-surfaces

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ be a K3 surface.
$G$ acts effectively and symplectically(fix the nowhere vanishing 2-form of $S$) on $S$.
Since the action is symplectic,quotient surface $S/G$ has only rational double points.
Let $S'$ be a desingularization of  $S/G$.

Q1 How to show that $b_1(S')$(the first Betti number of $S'$)=0?

Q2 In general,blowing-up of one point (maybe singular point or nosingular point of complex surfaces $X$) $X'\to X$ preserves the first betti number?
If $X$ has only  rational double point ,this is true? Give me a reference please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll first answer to the second question, and I assume you work over complex numbers. You only need to understand what happens for a single blow-up $X' \to X$ at $p \in X$ and can even look at the restriction to a small neighbourhood of $p$. For example, to understand the case when $X$ is smooth this is enough to see why the blow-up of $\Bbb C^2$ is simply connected.

In your situation, you need to look at double rational points, where this is also true because the exceptional divisor is simply connected (it's a graph of rational curves without cycles since it corresponds to ADE Dynkin diagrams) so you can use Mayer-Vietoris or you can by hand retract a ADE singularity on the exceptional divisor.

For the first question, this is true since a K3 is simply connected so again you can use Mayer-Vietoris.

I don't know if the second question holds in full generality, I guess not but can't think of a counter-example now.